# Internet Explorer full screen mode?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, fullscreen

I am building a web based free dynamic news reader (aka "autoplay" feature), that you can test it from here:

http://www.fivetechsoft.com/news

and I would like to implement a button to fullscreen it. Any hints?

Please notice that only IE is supported by now. Other browsers support comming soon.

Answer (score 14):

This will simply send F11.
Will be good enough for IE with weak security settings. This is something you might want to keep for internal use only, though:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function max() {
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.shell");
        wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: uugh. Solution works but if I saw that on a website on the internet I would quickly get off and never return.

Comment: Can this be used for video player(Jwplayer) for own custom fullscreen button (Check here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/33842428/1877909)

Answer (score 9):

Here is some information regarding that problem: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/dhtml/article.php/3470521

And to sum up the info, paste this bit of JS into the head of the code.

```
<script>
<!--
window.open("bigpage.html","fs","fullscreen=yes")
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have control of the machine, such as in a kiosk installation, you can launch IE in "kiosk mode" by running a batch file and supplying a URL: (save this string and name as "launch.bat")

```
start iexplore.exe -k "c:\Kiosk\default.htm"
```

or

```
start iexplore.exe -k "http://www.google.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
var splashWin = window.open("http://google.com", "win",
    "fullscreen=1,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0")
</script>
```

Google is your friend:

http://webfx.eae.net/dhtml/splashwin/splashwin.html

:)

Comment: This is your best bet for accomplishing full screen mode truly without user interaction. Using ActiveX requires security options to be very low.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a "best viewed in full-screen mode" notice in your page - that would work, too.

> [I want to programatically] fullscreen the currently viewed [window]

You see, what you're asking for is not possible in most browsers, and that is a Good Thing™

Imagine the possibilities - you enter a website, it programatically switches you to fullscreen and keeps you there if you try to go back. Living with uncloseable pop-ups was bad enough, manipulating the browser programatically would be a (security, usability, what-have-you) nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

This code gets closer, but still is opening a new window and the window caption remains visible:

window.open(location.href,'fullscreen','fullscreen,scrollbars')

so still it is not the same as pressing F11 :-(

Comment: Gets closer? It's the same as the first two. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Most professional games have a pre-coded button to interface the user to full screen,
as an option to the <kbd>F11</kbd> Key. It should not be viewed as a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve full screen on launch of ie:

Right click on the desktop launch icon...
and and in the Target Field, append `-k "http://www.google.com"`

The complete target field should look something like

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -k "http://www.google.com"
```

This disables all IE toolbars, addressbards you name it , you cant push F11 return to normal view either