# Exit full screen mode of IE 10 or less using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, fullscreen

I am unable to exit the full screen mode of IE using javascript.

Code for exiting full screen which i ma using is:

```
 docElement.msCancelFullScreen();
```

I also tried

```
 docElement.exitFullscreen();
```

I searches alot on web but nothing works for me.. Please help me..

Answer (score 3):

You can't, IE10 and below [don't support the FullScreen API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen). The *user* can easily exit it, but there's no IE API to do so. If there were an older, IE-specific API, they'd probably mention it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265028(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

I will just note, though, that the ms-prefixed function for exiting full screen mode is `msExitFullscreen`, not `msCancelFullScreen`.

Comment: If using "document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();" works for entering in full screen mode then why not it is possible to exit from full screen mode.

Comment: @SimranjeetKaur: I don't think that *does* work for entering full screen mode on IE10 and earlier.

Comment: I just tested in IE10 using MSFTs sample test page for the feature and it failed to enter full-screen.   http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/Workshop/samples/media/fullscreen/fullscreendemo.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function max() {
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.shell");
        wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Should probably mention the Stack overflow answer you copied this directly from or better yet, link to it.

Comment: Thanks, actually i copied this code from my notes i used to remeber such tricks. But after fast google i found similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen

Comment: @SimranjeetKaur What did you try? How did you implement this code?

Comment: @SimranjeetKaur, i just tried on ie9: 
`<script type="text/javascript">

    function max() {

        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.shell");

        wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");

    }

max();

</script>

<html>
<body>
</body>
<html>`

IE will ask about running unsafe content. You need to allow it to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

THe fullscreen API you are using is IE11 specific. It will not work in IE10 or less.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265028(v=vs.85).aspx

See [Internet Explorer full screen mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464332/internet-explorer-full-screen-mode)
For a workaround.

Comment: The sendkeys solution in the linked SO answer failed as well?