# Internet explorer 9 and 10 full-screen issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

My requirement is that, on the the click of a button in my website, it should go full screen.Its working using the full-screen api in safari, chrome and firefox, but not in I.E..Is there any proper way in which I can trigger full screen in I.E. 9 and I.E. 10? Also I have used the full screen api mentioned in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, which tells me to use "msRequestFullscreen". But in I.E. 11 it makes my website get cropped while in full-screen. Is there any resolution to this crop issue?

Comment: Are you saying the msRequestFullscreen works for IE9 and IE10, or you have two issues? IE11 cropping and how to fullscreen IE9/10?

Comment: Additionally, there is a table in the following link that says requestFullscreen is not implemented in browsers < IE11. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn254939(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Possible Duplicate, but looks like you have some options to take your website fullscreen: http://stackoverflow.com/a/464340/1670474 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/464341/1670474

Comment: @dannypaz I want to show the page I am currently in, in full screen mode. and also other than full-screen api is there any other way to get full screen in browsers < ie 11. Also the cropping issue happens in ie 11 while using msRequestFullscreen

Comment: can we have a sample code please?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people are having these issues. You might want to just work for Edge instead. Not judging, but my advice. Most people use chrome/firefox. And Microsoft Edge has a higher rate than IE. Just use javascript, make it autodetect the browser the user is using, and if he's using IE, just make an unclosable pop-up saying "Sorry, please use a different browser"
At least just until this IE fullscreen problem gets fixed.